# MOSS BDC Configuration Problem

Tags: sharepoint

Has anybody ever seen this error when working with the MOSS BDC?

```
Runtime Error in method AddBDCApplication.OnLoad of type
System.InvalidOperationException.The exception was System.InvalidOperationException:
Cannot use the Business Data Catalog from outside an Office Server context without 
explicitly setting the Shared Resource Provider by Name on the Business Data Catalog 
Sql Session Provider.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This person seems to have had the same issue.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/27459023/moss-2007-business-data.aspx

the answer: "Hi,

I had the same problem with a BDC control not displaying, getting the same error message in the log. The solution was that I had to use the primary adress to my site, and not one of the other adresses specified in Alternate Access Mapping or adress to extended web application if you are using this."